# How to send other params with rails3-jquery-autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-autocomplete

I want to send other params i.e hidden field values in `get_autocomplete_items(parameters)`

and I tried

```
 = rec.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_recruiter_name_job_applications_path, :placeholder=>"Recruiter name",:id_element=>"#phone", :param_name => 'search'
```

But ajax request is sending by same params not adding my other params

```
GET http://localhost:3000/job_applications/autocomplete_recruiter_name?term=test
```

I want url something like that

```
GET http://localhost:3000/job_applications/autocomplete_recruiter_name?term=test&search=series
```

so that I can access hidden field value in

```
def get_autocomplete_items(parameters)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.

```
= rec.hidden_field :recruitment_co_id
= rec.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_recruiter_name_job_applications_path(:recruitment_co_id=>''), :placeholder=>"Recruiter name",:id_element=>"#phone"

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#recruiter_recruitment_co_id").val($("#recruiter_name").attr("data-autocomplete"))
    $('#recruiter_name').bind('autocompleteselect', function(event, ui) {
      $("#recruiter_phone").val(ui.item.phone)
      $("#recruiter_email").val(ui.item.email)
    });

    $("#recruitment_co_name").bind('autocompleteselect', function(event, ui) {
        data_auto = $("#recruiter_recruitment_co_id").val() + ui.item.id
        $("#recruiter_name").attr("data-autocomplete",data_auto)
    });

});
```

Comment: I'm looking do to something similar http://stackoverflow.com/q/33531527/4379077, but I'm a js/jQuery newbie and I'm not quite following your logic.  Can you possibly help me out with my question or tell me where you actually put this jQuery code?  Also, is there anything in the gem that may make this easier?