# Add parameter to rails3-jquery-autocomplete (now rails-jquery-autocomplete) in addition to "term"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, autocomplete

When autocomplete sends the query string it contains a parameter of `term`.  See here:

```
 Started GET "/nodes/autocomplete_user_first_name?term=Mi" for 127.0.0.1
 Processing by NodesController#autocomplete_user_first_name as JSON
   Parameters: {"term"=>"Mi"}
```

I need to add a parameter to a value that's available in my view to yield something like this, using `node` as the parameter and 27 as the value:

```
Started GET "/nodes/autocomplete_user_first_name?term=Mi&node=27"
Processing by NodesController#autocomplete_user_first_name as JSON
   Parameters: {"term"=>"Mi", "node" => 27}
```

If I have to add via jQuery is a javascript file, please tell me where it should go.  I'm new to js/JQuery, but I understand it.  Thanks!

**EDIT**

The reason I need the node param is because I need to restrict the scope based on its value.

```
def get_autocomplete_items(parameters)
  items = active_record_get_autocomplete_items(parameters)
  items = items.where(:id => current_user.family_tree.memberships.pluck(:user_id))
         .where.not(:full_name => node.user_tags.pluck(:name))
end
```

Comment: Cant you add the node in the autocomplete_user_first_name action in the nodes controller? Or maybe even do .onkeyup when you type in the autocomplete to change the data-autocomplete attribute in the DOM or even do it on load and add the node attribute to also be passed.

Comment: How can I pass the node to the controller action?  That's the issue I'm having.  See edit above.

Comment: So are you trying to have multiple auto completes and restrict the ones you have already selected?

Comment: It's one autocomplete -- I want to restrict the ones in the same query as the original, which is why it's chained to the first where clause.